# How to convert Firebase Document Reference to Firebase Query?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I read the Firebase blog for using architecture components.
*Source:* https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components.html

Now to implement the same in my app, I would like to know how to convert the `Firebase Document Reference` to `Firebase Query` datatype.

Can someone help me with it?

I assume the code is not really necessary, but still providing it for better clarification.

***Note:***
1. I am using Firebase Firestore (the reference blog use firebase real-time database), and hence I have altered the code (referring another SO post).

***FirebaseQueryLiveData.java :***

```
public class FirebaseQueryLiveData extends LiveData<QuerySnapshot> {

//  Logging constant
private static final String TAG = "FirebaseQueryLiveData";

//  Query
private final Query query;

//  Listener
private final MyValueEventListener listener = new MyValueEventListener();
private ListenerRegistration listenerRegistration;

//  Handler
private final Handler handler = new Handler();

//  Flag to remove listener
private boolean listenerRemovePending = false;

//  Remove listener runnable
private final Runnable removeListener = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        listenerRegistration.remove();
        listenerRemovePending = false;
    }
};

public FirebaseQueryLiveData(Query query) {
    this.query = query;
}

@Override
protected void onActive() {
    super.onActive();
    Log.d(TAG, "onActive");

    //  Check flag
    if (listenerRemovePending) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(removeListener);
    } else {
        listenerRegistration = query.addSnapshotListener(listener);
    }

    //  Update flag
    listenerRemovePending = false;
}

@Override
protected void onInactive() {
    super.onInactive();
    Log.d(TAG, "onInactive");

    // Listener removal is schedule on a two second delay
    handler.postDelayed(removeListener, 2000);

    //  Update flag
    listenerRemovePending = true;
}

//  Listener definition
private class MyValueEventListener implements EventListener<QuerySnapshot> {

    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onEvent");

        //  Check for error
        if (e != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Can't listen to query snapshots: " + queryDocumentSnapshots
                    + ":::" + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        //  Set value if listening is successful
        setValue(queryDocumentSnapshots);
    }
}
}
```

***View model with Firebase collection reference (which is of Query datatype according to firebase docs.)***

```
//  Initialize Firebase variables
private static final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
private static final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

//  Query
private static final Query QUERY = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(COLLECTION_ORDERS)
        .whereEqualTo(ATTRIBUTE_USER_UID, Objects.requireNonNull(firebaseUser).getUid());

//  Firebase query live data
private final FirebaseQueryLiveData firebaseQueryLiveData =
        new FirebaseQueryLiveData(QUERY);

@NonNull
public LiveData<QuerySnapshot> getQuerySnapshotLiveData() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getQuerySnapshotLiveData");
    return firebaseQueryLiveData;
}
```

***Code with Document Reference:***

```
private static final DocumentReference documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        .collection("cart")
        .document(Objects.requireNonNull(firebaseUser).getUid());

private static final Query QUERY = documentReference;
```

In the above code snippet :
`private static final Query QUERY = documentReference;`
line shows the following error:

> Incompatible types.
>   Required: com.google.firebase.firestore.Query
>   Found: com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference

***Screenshot of the database:***

[image]

The document Id is used to fetch a document and hence I end up with Document reference and not Collection reference.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your database structure.

Comment: @AlexMamo Have added the screenhots

Comment: Perhaps you should just copy what's here instead: https://github.com/CodingDoug/firebase-jetpack

Comment: @DougStevenson I am still not good at kotlin. Is there any java code which I can refer to.

Comment: Just understand what it's trying to do and write the equivalent Java.  It shouldn't be that hard.  The patterns are all there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an exact answer but a doable hack, I used in my app.

Created another file for handling Document reference and used files according to the requirement.

***FirebaseDocumentLiveData.java***

```
public class FirebaseDocumentLiveData extends LiveData<DocumentSnapshot> {


    // Logging constant
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseQueryLiveData";

    // Document Reference
    private final DocumentReference documentReference;

    // Listener
    private final MyDocumentListener listener = new MyDocumentListener();
    // Handler
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private ListenerRegistration listenerRegistration;
    // Flag to remove listener
    private boolean listenerRemovePending = false;

    // Remove listener runnable
    private final Runnable removeListener = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            listenerRegistration.remove();
            listenerRemovePending = false;
        }
    };


    // Constructor
    public FirebaseDocumentLiveData(DocumentReference documentReference) {
        this.documentReference = documentReference;
    }


    // On active
    @Override
    protected void onActive() {
        super.onActive();
        Log.d(TAG, "onActive");

        // Check flag
        if (listenerRemovePending) {

            // Remove callbacks
            handler.removeCallbacks(removeListener);
        } else {

            // Add listener
            listenerRegistration = documentReference.addSnapshotListener(listener);
        }

        // Update flag
        listenerRemovePending = false;
    }

    // On inactive
    @Override
    protected void onInactive() {
        super.onInactive();
        Log.d(TAG, "onInactive");

        // Listener removal is schedule on a two second delay
        handler.postDelayed(removeListener, 2000);

        // Update flag
        listenerRemovePending = true;
    }

    // Listener definition
    private class MyDocumentListener implements EventListener<DocumentSnapshot> {

        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onEvent");

            // Check for error
            if (e != null) {

                // Log
                Log.d(TAG, "Can't listen to query snapshots: " + documentSnapshot
                        + ":::" + e.getMessage());
                return;
            }

            // Set value if listening is successful
            setValue(documentSnapshot);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the following error:

> Incompatible types.
>   Required: com.google.firebase.firestore.Query Found: com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference

At this particular line of code:

```
private static final Query QUERY = documentReference;
```

Because your are trying to assign a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference) object to a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query) object.

> How to convert Firebase Document Reference to Firebase Query?

This is actually not possible in Java since between these two classes there is no inheritance relationship. You could assign a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference) because it extends Query class but never a `DocumentReference`.

To get a single document, simply use `DocumentReference` object and never assign it another type of object.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I am well aware of the datatype mismatch. I can use document reference to do the necessary query, but I am trying to implement the architecture component in the way shown in the blog I mentioned.

Comment: I understand that but in that case you should implement the solution provided by Doug Stevenson in that blog step by step. I don't think there is anywhere in that blog such an assignment. So the error appears only because of that wrong assignment.